# Configure the root logger with java logging API

Tags: java, logging

how can I configure the behaviour of the root logger in the logging api? I don't want to configure the behaviour of each logger separately, instead it would be very convenient if I have a single property file where I can set the behaviour of all loggers.

Comment: Why can't I access the root log via getLogger("")??? Afterwards still only the logs in the main class produce the output

Answer (score -11, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) or [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) directly. It's much more comfortable and flexible.

**EDIT:**

If you want to configure your logging from a properties file, you should go with [Vinay Sajip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377706/configure-the-root-logger-with-java-logging-api/1377759#1377759). To get the root Logger inside your program and configure it using the API, you could ask for the Logger named "", like it says [here](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html)

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
```

Comment: Why is it much more comfortable? I have set up everything for logging with the logging api, it would not be comfortable to change everything.

Comment: @Xelluloid: Yes, you're right, it would be more comfortable if you had used log4j in the first place. I don't knew that you already went to far to change this sort of thing... my bad.

Comment: this does not work as I mentioned in my comment under my question it seems that I do not access the root logger by ""

Comment: oh sorry I've done a mistake =) now it works fine, thanks to you

Comment: -1, the questions says "using xyz library" how do i do "abc"... your answer says "Don't use xyz library... oh by the way here is what some other guy said" which is rude and not constructive. <br> That's like someone saying "my windows computer has a problem with abc" and then the person being asked the question responds with "Don't use Windows. You should be using Linux (or Mac)".

Comment: Saying "I would suggest to use Apache Commons Logging or log4j directly. It's much more comfortable and flexible." is only appropriate if the question is "I'm using java.util.logging but not happy with it. what other similar libraries are there that I can use?"

Answer (score 9):

Use the following to get the root logger:

```
Logger system = Logger.getLogger("");
```

You can now access the root logger as any other logger.

In my case I was willing to make it quiet. I succeeded to do it with the following code:

```
private static void setLevel(Logger pLogger, Level pLevel) {
    Handler[] handlers = pLogger.getHandlers(); 
    for (Handler h : handlers) {
        h.setLevel(pLevel);
    }
    pLogger.setLevel(pLevel);
}

...

setLevel(system, Level.OFF);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you mean the `java.util.logging` (JUL) implementation: if so, have a look at the relevant part of the Java Almanac. The overview information for JUL configuration is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.8). Basically, the approach *is* to use a single configuration file for all loggers.

**Update:** Removed the link to the Java Almanac, as it is no longer valid (linkrot strikes again), as mentioned in jschoen's comment. Please use Google to find alternative sources of information.

Comment: Don't know if I caught it on a bad day or not but your link to Java Almanac seems to be broke.